# Angular - highcharts-angular / bootstrap / chart not growing to parent size width

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I'm using Angular with bootstrap and Highcharts / Highcharts-angular

I have added a grid with charts of in but when I change the size of the grids the charts are not growing 100% width.

Here is the code:

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="changeGrid(12)">1 Column</button>
<button (click)="changeGrid(6)">2 Columns</button>
<button (click)="changeGrid(4)">3 Columns</button>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-{{grid}}" *ngFor="let item2 of items">

            <div class="card">

                 <div class="card-body">
                                    
                    <highcharts-chart style="width:100% !important; display:block;"
                        [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
                        [constructorType]="item2.options.constructorType"
                        [(update)]="updateFlag"
                        [oneToOne]="oneToOneFlag"
                        [options]="item2.options">
                    </highcharts-chart>
                </div>

            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HighchartsService } from 'hc.service';

import * as Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import HStockTools from "highcharts/modules/stock-tools";

HStockTools(Highcharts);

export class AppComponent {

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chart: Highcharts.Chart | null | undefined;
  data: any;
  updateFlag = false;
  oneToOneFlag: boolean = true;
  chartTypes = [];
  options: any;
  grid: undefined;



loadData() {
  this.data = this.hcService.data();
}

changeGrid(grid: any) {
  this.data[0].layout.gridcols = grid;
  this.updateFlag = true;
}
```

The grid is growing but the charts are not expanding 100% width with the grid / card / parent

Hoe can I fix this in this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions"
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"
  ></highcharts-chart>
</div>
```

If you want to fit container with contain chart manipulate  width at CSS style.

```
/* .container {
  width: 100%;
  height:400px;
  display: block;
} */
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height:400px;
  display: block;
}
```

Live demo: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-fwdbze?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Documentation: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#online-examples

Comment: It doesn't work when you dynamically change the size of the parent. I added <div class="card-body" style="width:100%; display:block">
                    <highcharts-chart style="width:100%; display:block;" ... and it won't resize to 100% when the parent is resized unless it's when the page loads. When you resize without reloading the page the chart doesn't resize to fit 100%. I need to resize the parent at runtime without reloading the page

Comment: It seems to work if I use this:   windowUpdate() {
    var el = document;
    var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    event.initEvent('resize', true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(event);
    this.updateFlag = true;
  } but only if I run it twice on a button click...so I need to click on the button twice

Comment: Also when I manually resize the browser window the chart seems to update and stretch itself

Comment: I need to check it, Please replicate this and show it at the demo.

Comment: @deszok I have experienced the same with my column charts (line charts don't show this behavior). A small part of the chart to the right is always overflowing, and therefore hidden, but if I just resize the window it fixes itself. Surely this is a bug? Anyone got any updates? Thanks

Comment: @AlePorro could you prepare a simplified code version of this behavior?